# how to convert image to base_64 before save to storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64

I want to convert image data to base64 string 
I am already doing this technique

```
file 1
detail_project2.html 
<form method="post" name="frm_pdf_handler" id="frm_pdf_handler" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/laporan/pdf_handler') ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">
 <input type="text" id="foo_element" name="grppenyerapankeuangan"/>
<button>Create PDF</button>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {


var chart1_data = <?php echo $arrlinechart; ?>;
var chart1_options = {};
var chart1_element = 'chart_realisasi_keuangan';
var chart1_type = google.visualization.ColumnChart;
drawGoogleChart2(chart1_data, chart1_options, chart1_element, chart1_type);
});
</script>
```

file 2 devoops.js//from google charts

```
function drawGoogleChart2(chart_data, chart_options, element, chart_type) {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_data);
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
 var image=chart.getImageURI();//convert canvas to image file from google   chart
$("#foo_element").val('data:image/base64,' + image);//store base64 to input field before delivered to php controller
}
}
chart.draw(data, chart_options);
}
```

file 3
pdf_handler.php (codeigniter controller)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pdf_handler extends CI_Controller {
 function index(){
echo "<img src='".$this->input->post("foo_element")."'"."/>";
}
}
```

base64 string is successfully generated but cannot apears image as my espectation. someone can help me please?

Comment: `$("#foo_element")` is an image element? if yeas then you need to change src of element. like `$("#foo_element").attr('src', <your base64 variable here>)`

Comment: no it's not.  $("#foo_element") is variabel who I use to store  base64 value before I delivere it to codeigniter controller

Comment: OK, Then find img element by selector (if not then add to html page) and apply src to it as your base64 string is successfully generated and you want display it in image.

Comment: please look at my answer on file 3 pdf_handler.php
I am already doing that in php file like this echo "<img src='".$this->input->post("foo_element")."'"."/>" , my problem is when I convert google chart canvas to base64 the result failed to render to be an image again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[solved]
```

this is actualy happen.

when I am doing this

```
var image=chart.getImageURI();
```

variabel image is not image file but base64 encoding format
so my mistake is
when I am trying to convert base64 again 
like this

```
$("#foo_element").val('data:image/base64,' + image);//my fatal mistake
```

so, this is what I necesary to do

```
$("#foo_element").val(image);//my revision
```

and finaly everything work fine.
thank you All :D

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set it like this:

```
$('#foo_element').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + image + '" />');
```

**Update**

Can you please attach the html from what this line outputs (pdf_handler.php),

```
echo "<img src='".$this->input->post("grppenyerapankeuangan")."'"."img/>";
```

it looks like it should be like this

```
echo "<img src='".$this->input->post("grppenyerapankeuangan")."' />";
```

Also in my example it specifies image type as png, not sure if image type is mandatory..

Comment: $("#foo_element") is an input element who I use to store base64 before I deliver it to php controller.

Comment: echo "<img src='".$this->input->post("grppenyerapankeuangan")."' />";
still not work